# Check DataGridView for certain text

Tags: c#, datagridview

So, what I have a datagridview with a couple of columns where one of them is vehicle name. But that column contains classnames of vehicles (for example the classname is "jonzie_30CSL" the actual name of that car would be "Ferrari Enzo".

So my question is how would I translate that classname which is listed in the datagridview to the actual car name?

I've tried a couple of things but I coudln't find anything that worked.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The knowledge that you have about what a certain car name means when it's written as a class can be but in a data structure where the class name and the real name correspond:

```
 //your data structure
 Dictionary<string, string> carsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

 carsDictionary.Add("jonzie_30CSL", "Ferrari Enzo");
 carsDictionary.Add("someClassNme", "Actual Car Name");

 //prints "Ferrari Enzo"
 Console.WriteLine(carsDictionary["jonzie_30CSL"]);
```

You can use this to extract any real name by:

```
string realName = carsDictionary["nameFromDataGridView"];
```

Comment: I see how this would work, but I want to replace the classname with the actual car name like you did, but straight into the datagridview?